# nlog.config- file not found .Net core 3.1 and Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nlog

I am new to Docker and I am getting an error from the below line in the Main method, it's a .net core 3.1 API with Docker,
When it tries to initialize the Nlog, the code unable to find the nlog.config, the file is configured to copy always.

```
var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

this is the error I am getting,

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Failed to load NLog LoggingConfiguration. 
  Searched the following locations:
     - /app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/nlog.config
```

It is working fine when running with IIS.

Thanks in advance
Aabid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell based on the information you have provided. Do you have any additional information - a Dockerfile that you could provide/show relevant lines of? There are some guidelines for dockerizing an Asp.Net Core application over on the [docker examples](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/).

If your application works in IIS but not docker then I'd suggest that your nlog.config file isn't part of your container. Perhaps check that your nlog.config file is copied to the output directory during a build? (in VS2019 right click on the file, then properties, then set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer")

[image: nlog.config Properties]

You can build your container and then enter a bash session to browse the directories/etc by using the following docker commands:

Build the container using:

`docker build -t nlog-example .`

Enter a bash terminal session using:

`docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash nlog-example`

(note, nlog-example is the docker tag in my example, but yours may be different)

Comment: Hello, The file property is set to copy always, I  am running from VS 2019, and I am not sure to get the docker file ("- a Dockerfile that you could provide/show relevant lines of"), I checked the container files in visual studio output and I could see the file in this app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/

Comment: I was using the NLog.Config package and the nlog.config were referred from the package path, now I removed the package and added the nlog.config manually to the project, now it started to work.Thanks

Comment: Should have also pointed you at the guide here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

Comment: @Aabidabdulsalam I guess you were facing same issue as my following answer: Linux container.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional answer for those who are dealing with this environment:
`Docker` + `Linux`:

As `On Linux, the file system is case sensitive`, let's simply change config name exactly same what you see in images, case-sensitive.

but in another hand, set `LogManager.LogFactory.SetCandidateConfigFilePaths` is also necessary if renaming not work.

Here my config name is `NLog.Config`:

```
var fullPath = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith("nlog.config", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

LogManager.LogFactory.SetCandidateConfigFilePaths(new[] { fullPath });
var config = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
return NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(config).GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell what version of NLog you were using? Are you using single-file-publish on NetCore ? Would like to fix the issue, so NLog works out-of-the-box.

Comment: @RolfKristensen that would be nice.  we are using `NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.10.0`. developers aren't aware that file names are case-sensitive in Linux. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Yes but to fix it, then I need to know why it fails. It would be great if you could create an issue here https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues and attach sample project, that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Actually it is historic reason, in git source control, this config file got differnet name format. all microservices are coding `nlog.config` as config filename, but when I started dockerizing all services, I found different config names in Linux images: `nlog.config`, `Nlog.Config`, `Nlog.config`, `NLog.config` and so on. Actually the simpliest way is to rename those files to same format: `nlog.config`, which can skip the issue as well.

Comment: Yes keeping everything lowercase on the linux-platform makes everything much simpler. NLog only see "NLog.config" and "nlog.config" (Fails when NLog.Config on Linux)